# Comparing tuples from two files in Pig

Tags: tuples, apache-pig

I want to compare tuples from two different files using Pig. If tuples are mirror image of each other, I want that tuple into file-f3.

If f1 has the following tuples

```
(1 2)
(3 4)
```

and f2 has following tuples

```
(5 6)
(4 3)
```

Since (3 4) is a mirror image of (4 3), we need to store this value in f3. Thus, f3 would be

```
(3 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply inner join the 2 data sets like below:

```
data1 = LOAD '$data1' USING AvroStorage();
data2 = LOAD '$data2' USING AvroStorage();

output = JOIN data1 BY ($0, $1), data2 BY ($1, $0);
output2 = FOREACH output GENERATE data1.$0, data1.$1;
```